# Bootstrap 4 Card cut (Loading through ajax call with Shuffle.js), on Microsoft Edge works fine

Tags: bootstrap-4

[Website Link](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/alexis-drakopoulos.com/blog.html)

When I click Load more on Chrome, the card is cut halfway.

It seems to have loaded in the background because if I resize chrome the card appears in full.

Images showing the issue:

[image]

and here is how it's supposed to look:

[image]